# Assign an only select value, to a only one variable

Tags: mysql, lua

I'm stating with LUA and SQL statements. I have try, and I can display a SELECT or make an UPDATE, INSERT ... but i don't know how to assign an only returned select value, to a variable

```lua
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"

env  = mysql.mysql()
conn = env:connect('table','user','pass','server')
--print(env,conn)

cursor,errorString = conn:execute([[select id from agent where extension = '9072']])
--print(cursor,errorString)

row = cursor:fetch ({}, "a")

while row do
   print(string.format("%s", row.id))
   row = cursor:fetch (row, "a")
end

-- close everything
cursor:close()
conn:close()
env:close()
```

I expect somehing like:
value=33

Comment: Do the examples help you? https://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```
sql = "select id from agent where extension = '9072' limit 1"
cursor,errorString = conn:execute(sql)
value = nil
if cursor then
  row = cursor:fetch ({}, "a")    -- we'll have 0 or 1 rows
  if row then value = row.id end
end
```